How to prevent a SharedFlow collect values when the activity resumes?
I have found an issue where SharedFlow does not collect values when the activity is open. So I set replay = 1, which worked fine initially.
However, I found that when the app is sent to the background (eg. using the home button) and then brought back to the foreground, the SharedFlow collects values again, which seems to be because of the replay = 1 setting.
What can I do to prevent SharedFlow from collecting values multiple times upon resuming the activity? Are there any alternative approaches or configurations to handle this scenario effectively?
Here is an example of my code
ViewModel
 private val _uiEvent =
        MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent>(
            replay = 1
        )

 fun onUiEvent(): SharedFlow<UiEvent> =
        _uiEvent


fun callAPI() {
        callAPI.excute(request = Unit)
            .onStart { updateUiEvent(UiEvent.ShowLoading) }
            .onCompletion { updateUiEvent(UiEvent.HideLoading) }
            .onEach { // Do something }
            .catch { // Do something }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

private fun updateUiEvent(uiEvent: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.emit(uiEvent)
        }
    }


Activity

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.callAPI()
        setContent {
            SetUiEvent()
        }
}

@Composable
private fun SetUiEvent() {
    SingleEventEffect(viewModel.onUiEvent()) { event ->
        when (event) {
            UiEvent.ShowLoading -> {
                *** Here is not collect
            }

            UiEvent.HideLoading -> {
                // Do something
            }
    }
}

SingleEventEffect
@Composable
fun <T : Any> SingleEventEffect(
    launchedEffect: Flow<T>,
    lifeCycleState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    collector: ((T) -> Unit)
) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    LaunchedEffect(launchedEffect) {
        lifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(lifeCycleState) {
            launchedEffect.collect(collector)
        }
    }
}


Use a stateflow and align your UI with current state. Don't use one-time events (sharedflow) to manipulate UI from viewmodel level.

@Pawel Do you really recommend using StateFlow? For example, to show a dialog, I have to set a flag to true and then reset it to false every time. Also, when navigating from screen A to B and back to A, the StateFlow still shows the state for screen B. Managing these flags seems cumbersome.

Screen B should not interact with StateFlow that hold state of screen A? It's unclear how your viewmodel hierarchy is structured. Ideally you want your UI to just consume the state and enter it, without relying on its current/previous state as such state propagation gets messy really fast.

@Pawel Suppose I have an AActivity with an AViewModel that uses StateFlow to hold a flag like isNavigateToB. Before navigating to BActivity, I need to perform some actions in the ViewModel (e.g., calling an API) and then set isNavigateToB to true.
The problem is that when I return from BActivity, AViewModel still has isNavigateToB set to true, causing repeated navigation to BActivity. This makes managing the flag difficult.
Therefore, I wonder why we should use StateFlow for handling one-time events?

Navigating to other activity is a peculiar case as it will cause all viewmodels collectors to unsubscribe and might lead to viewmodel itself being destroyed. I'd still say setting up the flag is correct but it should be lowered as soon as ActivityB is launched and mayhaps enter an odd "InActivityB" state until activityA is resumed and feeds result of activityB (if any) back to viewmodel...

SharedFlow is not designed for UI setup stuff. Probably you should change the architecture of this solution and use StateFlow why? - to make sure the ui state is always set with latest known data state. Using SharedFlow there are possibilities that you reach incorrect screen state by some event handling edge cases.
As far as your question - to make sure event is handled only once you should use Channel or SharedFlow with replay = 0(doc replay - the number of values replayed to new subscribers (cannot be negative, defaults to zero).)
